# Changing the Order of Columns in a Table Permanently Using T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server

My table is `student_register` and has four columns like

```
1. srno 
2. firstname
3. lastname
4. middlename
```

I want the column `middlename` in third position permanently in table using SQL Server 2005 query.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that is possible using `sql query` because the columns in the table are not ordered .You have to re create the table.But why do u want to re order the columns ? You can always use `Select` query to specify the order of columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do what you want without dropping and readding the table.  To see how Management Studio accomplishes this (at least in 2012, but I think this applies to 2005 too), go to Management Studio's `Options` > `Designers` > `Table and Database Designer` > Uncheck `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`.

Once you do that you can go in to the table designer, change the order of the columns and instead of clicking "Save", click "Save Change Script" to see the SQL.

Here is what SQL 2012 would generate:

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table_1
    (
    TEst1 nchar(10) NULL,
    Test3 nchar(10) NULL,
    Test2 nchar(10) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_Table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_Table_1 (TEst1, Test3, Test2)
        SELECT TEst1, Test3, Test2 FROM dbo.Table_1 WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Table_1
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_Table_1', N'Table_1', 'OBJECT' 
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: If you let the designer do it instead of generating script do you lose the data in your table or does it copy it in for you?

Comment: @schmidlop I believe it will execute the same code that it uses to generate the script.  As you can see in the script, it does keep your data intact, as long as all you're doing is changing the column position.

Comment: Yeah, agreed, I missed the insert...select when I skimmed the script above

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a one time thing the simplest approach would be to use Visual Database Tools for that

**[How to: Change Column Order (Visual Database Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337556%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) SQL Server 2005**

- In Object Explorer, right-click the table with columns you want to reorder and click Design (Modify in SP1 or earlier). The table opens in Table Designer.
- Select the box to the left of the column name that you want to reorder.
- Drag the column to another location within the table.

To do it in TSQL you'll need:

- create a temp table with correct order of columns
- insert data into temp table from original table
- drop original table
- rename temp table to original name